# Can some tags be merged?

Tags: feature-request, tags

Is there a way to merge some tags. For example, there is an 'adsense' tag and a 'google-adsense' tag. It would make more sense if they were one tag. There are a few other tags like that, but cannot think of them at the top of my head. Just offering the suggestion.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I agree. We can make synonyms for tags which is something I've been meaning to do myself. If you could help me make a list of duplicate tags like the one you mentioned I'll be more then happy to go through them and make synonyms for them.

Comment: I will work on a list for you. Is there a page where I can see a list of all tags?

Comment: [All tags](http://webmasters.stackexchange.com/tags) I'll see if I can find some synonyms and add them to [this community wiki question for discussion](http://meta.webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/434/list-of-possible-tags-that-are-synonyms)

Answer (score 3):

If you feel that tags should be merged -- great!

Just open a meta topic here, or answer the existing one, and we'll merge them.

It is also possible to propose synonyms if you have 2500 reputation and at least 5 votes in the tag you are "synonymizing".